# Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, objective-c

Ao criar um projeto e instalar o cocoapods e o alamofire, ao rodar ele so da este erro e nao da build no projeto, mesmo vazio somente importando o alamofire

> Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1

ja tentei vários tópicos mas sem sucesso.
se alguém ja passou por isso, me ajude que estou a horas neste erro

Comment: desinstala o Xcode beta e instala a versão 8.1 Swift 3.0.2

Comment: Ja esta a versao Version 8.3 (8E162) nao beta @LeoDabus

Comment: então espera sair os updates das frameworks em questao

Comment: @LeoDabus estou tentando usar o Alamofire, intalando via cocoapods. Voce me indica algum pra que eu possa substituir?

Comment: URLSession nativa do Swift

Answer (score 1):

O problema se dá porque o módulo Alamofire está compilado na versão 3.0.2 e, agora, você tenta compilar seu projeto na versão 3.1, o que impede do módulo ser importado para o projeto. Para mais detalhes, clique [aqui](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72751)!

Eu estava tendo o mesmo problema, inclusive com o mesmo módulo Alamofire instalado via POD. Apenas limpar o projeto não resolveu pra mim. Mas consegui corrigir o problema da seguinte forma:

1. eu removi o Alamofire do projeto
2. limpei o projeto (CMD+SHIFT+K)
3. atualizei o POD (pod update), e
4. adicionei o Alamofire de volta ao podfile e mandei instalar.

Espero que isso o ajude.

Comment: Eu removi o alamofire e usei o URLsession mesmo, não tinha usado antes porque não estava conseguindo usar "basic authentication" mas agora que consegui, abandonei os frameworks. Mas Obrigado!